# Why are butterflies not affected by the Black Iron Sickness?

Tags: zetsuen-no-tempest

In Zetsuen No Tempest, there was this sickness that turned everything into black iron, which is where its name came from. However, from what I can remember, I am sure there was no explanation in the anime to this question.

**Why are butterflies not affected by the Black Iron Sickness?**

Was this ever revealed in the manga? I am positive that it is not mentioned in the anime series, or on [Zetsuen No Tempest Wiki](http://zetsuennotempest.wikia.com), but was there ever an explanation for this? And if this was in the anime, would you please include a reference to the episode?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: Maybe because of the same reason magicians are not: because butterflies are surrounded by a magic field.